# Matlab plotting is not well since values are not unique in x axis

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot sales in the store in every 30 minutes, Hours and halves on x axis and quantities in y axis.

For instance I have a dataset as,

```
x= 
    500 0.1
    100 0.2
    232 1.1
    22  1.2
    21  2.1
    123 2.2
    34  9.1
    233 9.2
    12  10.1
    22  10.2
    32  11.1
    .    .
    .    .
    .    . 
    167  0.1
    255  0.2
    89   1.1
    67   1.2
    .     .
    .     .
    .     .
```

So I would like to plot it like `plot(x(:,2),x(:,1))`  but matlab just mixes up and tries put them descending order.

I tried axis tigth and xtick  but they dont work. My sample code;

```
figure;
plot(x(:,2),x(:,1));
datetick('x',HH:MM:SS);
```

Anyone can help me?[image]

I would like to plot it like,

[image]

Comment: I am confused as Matlab do too. What do you exactly want by saying 500 0.1 and 167  0.1?do you mean y should become both 500 and 167 when x = 0.1 or what?

Comment: What output do you expect here?  Maybe you'd like `scatter` better?

Comment: After reading this post 3 times I think I got what you mean. Do you want to add a third axis to track on the time? So maybe you want raw data look like 500 0.1 00:00:00 ... 167  0.1 00:30:00?

Comment: I would like have x(:,2) values in x axis x(:,1) values in y axis. Yes as you said. 500 0.1 and 167 0.1 also.

Comment: What is raw? Sorry I did not understand :(